# why do we need to pass a new variable in closures

Tags: javascript, closures

I'm reading http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-closures-with-ease/    and I had a question about this line of code.

Note that for formatting purposes I removed the comments in the original code

```
function celebrityIDCreator (theCelebrities) {
var i;
var uniqueID = 100;
for (i = 0; i < theCelebrities.length; i++) {
    theCelebrities[i]["id"] = function (j)  { 
        return function () {
            return uniqueID + j; 
        } () 
    } (i); 
}
```

​
    return theCelebrities;
}

---

I see that the j is meant to pass the value of i in the function, but I don't understand why we can't just use "i" so the code reads like this

```
theCelebrities[i]["id"] = function (i) {
return function () {
    return uniqueID+ i;
} ()
```

each time, the uniqueID will capture whatever value "i" is in the loop and update.

---

Can someone explain why it is necessary to create the variable j rather than just passing i?

Comment: In short, i inside function (i) is not the same as i in theCelebrities[i]["id"] - it's a formal parameter. Whereas in final brakets (i) i is argument.

Answer (score 0):

In the failing case (capturing `i` directly), when a closure captures `i`, it captures a reference to it, not a copy.

Therefore, when the code in the closure runs, it uses the value of `i` *at the time the closure code runs*, rather than at the time the closure was created.  And at the time the closure code runs, the value of `i` is `theCelebrities.length` because the loop has finished by then.

In the working case (capturing the value of `i` via `j`), the value of `i` is transferred into `j` *at the time the closure is created*, so subsequent changes to `i` have no effect on the closure.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with variable scope in javascript.

When you do

```
return function () {
    return uniqueID+ i;
}
```

the anonymous function sees `i` which is incremented in the for loop. When the anonymous function is executed, `i` will be the last iterated value. `i` is seen in the loop and is preserved in the anonymous function.

However, when you do

```
function (j)  { 
        return function () {
            return uniqueID + j; 
        } () 
    } (i);
```

you are creating a new scope which is visible only to the anonymous function. This is why you have to pass it in. The anonymous function will use `j` as it was passed in. Further iterations will leave `j` unaffected.

Answer (score 0):

You may also think in terms of `parameters` and `arguments`, like you would normally do in any other programming language. So, answering this question:

> why we can't just use "i" so the code reads like this

```
theCelebrities[i]["id"] = function (i) {
    return function () {
        return uniqueID+ i;
    } ()
```

You can't, because `i` in function (i) is a formal parameter and not the argument. Whereas in this case:

```
... = function (j)  { 
    return function () {
        return uniqueID + j; 
    } () 
} (i);
```

`i` is an argument. It is exactly what you would like to feed your function with.